# VS2012 Collapse solution

Tags: visual-studio-2012, solution-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Collapse all files at once in Solution Explorer window in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273552/collapse-all-files-at-once-in-solution-explorer-window-in-visual-studio)

How do you collapse a solution in Visual Studio 2012 with just one shortcut ?

Not currently selected project but the whole solution! Power Commands support collapsing the selected project and with manually selecting the solution, it would actually collapse the solution but that's not what I want.

After using the shortcut, I want to collapse the whole solution explorer no matter what project is selected, no matter what files are opened or used.

Does anyone know an addon or anything else for this?